# Can we use owasp zap for mobile application

Tags: security, owasp, zap

I'm trying to build a react native application,(mobile app). Can I use owasp zap for security testing. Or owasp zap only for website and web application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see this FAQ which includes a video :) https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/can-zap-be-used-to-test-mobile-apps/

Comment: Thanks but that link says how to test web application using a mobile, but what i need is to test for an apk, can you please kindly check and verify.

Comment: ZAP can test anything which supports web protocols like HTTP(S) and websockets. If your app doesnt provide those then no, it cannot test it.